# Weird response from beautifulsoup/urllib, requests and robobrowser

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests, robobrowser

I was trying to login using robobrowser in this website http://www.juicyads.com/login2.php

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

browser = RoboBrowser(
            history=True,
            user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/34.0.1847.116 Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36'
)
url = 'http://www.juicyads.com/login2.php'
browser.open(url)
print browser.response.text
```

but it returned JS code and few lines of headers and footer.

I tried to open this website in browser after disable the javascript but it seems content is in html itself not javascript generated

I again tried with `requests` library

```
import requests
a = requests.get(url)
print a.text
print a.content   # both a.text and a.content returned exactly same response
```

I again went for native library (urllib2) but no success.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

a = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print BeautifulSoup(a.text)
```

As I said I'm trying to login into this site using robobrowser.and for that I have to find that form which says

```
<form method=POST action=http://www.juicyads.com/login2.php style='margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;'>
// some input fields
</form>
```